# The correct way to programmatically process a large number of files from a HDD

Tags: c#, windows, file

I've got a folder with 100K files ranging from small several byte text files to larger 10s of MB binaries to 100s of MB resource files, and I'd like to take the MD5 hash of all of them to compare to a list of valid MD5s.

I wrote a trivial snippet in C# to run a Parallel.ForEach and add jobs to a ThreadPool to load the files into memory and take their hash.

With my 4 core/8 thread CPU, and on a Solid State Drive this is OK, the random access is no problem and my drive was pulling close to its maximum read rate. However, as one would expect, on a spinning disk HDD, I'm not even getting close to max throughput.

So my question is, what options do I have to process an arbitrary set of files in parallel on a HDD? I'm not dead set on a particular language, but if I had to pick one, C# + .NET Core would be good enough.

As much as I'd like some magical multi-platform multi-filesystem approach, I realize that might not be possible, and so if I can get some reasonable solution on Windows and the filesystems it supports that would be good enough.

I have no way of changing the folder setup, so something like creating a TAR isn't an option, but honestly if something like a localized defragmentation is reasonable maybe that's a valid approach...

For reference, here's the code I quickly wrote up just to test:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Linq;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MultiMD5Hash
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string dirName = args[0];
            int fileCount = GetAllFilesInDirectory(dirName).Count();
            Console.WriteLine($"GetFileCount = {fileCount}");

            Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
            Parallel.ForEach(GetAllFilesInDirectory(dirName), (f) => GetHashOfFile(f));
            stopWatch.Stop();

            Console.WriteLine($"MD5 of {fileCount} files took {stopWatch.Elapsed} ms");
        }

        static IEnumerable<string> GetAllFilesInDirectory(string path)
        {
            foreach (string file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
            {
                yield return file;
            }
        }

        static byte[] GetHashOfFile(string file)
        {
            using (var md5 = MD5.Create())
            using (var stream = File.OpenRead(file))
            {
                return md5.ComputeHash(stream);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

On a fairly recently purchased SATA3 HDD it ranges from 13-35 MB/s, which is far lower than its average peak of ~100MB/s sequential read (given that this is random access, this makes sense though).

On my SATA3 SSD, it achieves between 515-530 MB/s, which matches its peak random read speeds (which is fairly straightforward).

Comment: When you run this what IOPS and bandwidth is being used?  A HDD has a max bandwidth of approx. 125MBps, and IOPS of approx 180, with averages below this.    So if you are hitting these limits, then the problem is not your program but simply the amount and type of operations that you need to do.  For which the only solution is reducing your IO

Comment: @jason.kaisersmith, thanks for replying. I'll re-run my HDD tests and post the results in the question, since I think I made a mistake initially with the code. As an aside, 'reducing your IO' -> In this case, my operation is fairly straightforward (for every file in a directory tree -> get the MD5 hash), I'm not sure exactly what other recourse there is to try and get it done as fast as possible.

Comment: Added results as well.

Comment: Even though you are not hitting the max throughput on the HDD, it is still your bottleneck.   HDD performance is complex (somebody from HP once explained this in detail, long story short, it is very difficult to get max throughput).  You could try (this is a theory, I cannot test it) executing sequentially in a loop rather than a parallel loop, as it might not overload the HDD so much and be more efficient.  In a parallel loop you probably have a mixture of random & sequential reads with the head all over the place, in a normal loop the impact from random reads may be less.  Try it and see.

Comment: You call `GetAllFilesInDirectory` twice. This creates an extra load on the disk. Use `Directory.GetFiles()` and save the result to a local variable.

Comment: Thanks @jason.kaisersmith, I'll give that a shot. Though, I suspect a sequential loop is going to rely on me effectively 'getting lucky' and hoping there isn't much fragmentation.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, if this wasn't test code I'd agree but the first call is almost entirely irrelevant on both disks and takes a fraction of a second. Removing it entirely has almost no change to the overall profile.